# OpenCL and indirect recursion

Tags: recursion, opencl

Opencl does not support recursive functions but does this cover indirect versions too?

```
void recursiveA(int *a,int b) // call this first to start recursion
{
     a[b]=3; 
     if(b<10)
     {
        recursiveB(a,b+1);  // A calls B
     }
}


void recursiveB(int *a, int b)
{
     a[b]=3;
     if(b<10)
     {
        recursiveA(a,b+1); // B calls A while A still not finished before
                           // and entry point & arguments of A are corrupt ?
     }

}
```

instead of

```
void recurse(int *a, int b)
{
     a[b]=3;
     if(b<10)
     {
        recurse(a,b+1); // some OpenCL devices does not have the ability so this is not
                        // possible in OpenCL
     }

}
```

So, can we call a "R" function from another function even if first "R" is not finished? Those functions use only same constant addresses for arguments everytime we call them?
**Do I have to use a custom "stack" implementation to do indirect recursion until Opencl 2.0 is released?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenCL does not support recursive control flow, which includes mutual recursion. Therefore, to ensure that your code works properly on every platform you may wish to target, you should refrain from using any form of recursion, and instead write your algorithms using an iterative approach.

In practice, the OpenCL compilers may be able to handle certain recursive algorithms just fine. For example, if your function is tail-recurisve, then the compiler can produce a non-recurisve form by applying standard tail-call optimisation techniques. I've just tried the second recursive code snippet you posted, and it was accepted by multiple OpenCL compilers. The first code snippet caused them all to crash, which indicates that they couldn't apply the necessary transformations to avoid recursive calls (though clearly they should produce a suitable error message rather than crashing).

So, you may be able to get away with simple recursion with some OpenCL implementations, but for maximum portability across different platforms I would strongly recommend that you avoid it.

Comment: In GLSL, I usually implement recursion [using macro expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77470186/975097). This should be possible in OpenCL as well, as long as the maximum depth of recursion is known at compile-time.